# Make application portable, bundled (not .Net)

Tags: bundle, bundler, portability

I have an application which consist's of these files:

```
start.exe <-- main executable
libssh2.dll
libcurl.dll
libeay32.dll
zlib1.dll
ssleay32.dll
inf2.cl
ffd.co
```

.... and other files with different extensions. Application read these files during work.

How can i merge all these files into one `start.exe` without changing code (i can't, i do not have a source code). I know that themida can do the trick but when i use demo i have a crash...

Thanks!

Comment: Especially as you don't have access to the sources I think your only realistic option will be to wrap all the files needed in an installer ([Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is great, and free) and have the receiving end install the app.  I know that that's not what you want, but I'm afraid what you want to do just isn't possible.

Comment: @fvu, thanks for your answer. But it is possible with Themida Xbundler (i tried for another applications earlier) but with this application themida won't work and i try find analog of themida xblunder

Comment: If that's the case you should contact Oreans, the publisher of Themida for a possible solution.  What they seem to be doing is not trivial at all, and I can imagine that there are limitations to what can be achieved using their technology, where those limits are and whether the crash you got is a bug that can be solved by them, or a technology limitation, is a question only they can answer.